# What file does FromFile pull from?

Tags: c#, fromfile

This is my first time trying to use images in my code. I cannot figure out what file the FromFile command pulls from.

```
firstDice.Image = Image.FromFile(fDice.ToString() + ".png");
```

I am trying to get the image to correspond with whatever the random number fDice is.

Here is my error message:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: '5.png'

Comment: You need to have that file in the current directory. Or you need to build a full or relative path to the file

Comment: Not exactly sure what your question is here.  The error message indicates what filename the `fDice.ToString() + ".png"` piece yielded.  Is that not the file you want?

Comment: You probably mean "Directory" not "File", since the file is fairly obvious from the error message.

Comment: @EatPeanutButter since its a "dice" it can be random between 1-6. The problem I am having is that the image is not displaying in the picturebox like it should be. I am just not sure if there is a specific file that I should save my images into that the fromfile command tries to pull them from.

Comment: @BrandonLukowski do you have image files called `1.png`, `2.png`, etc?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter Yes I do.

Comment: @BrandonLukowski then see the comments/answers about ensuring you're looking in the correct path

Comment: Thanks for the help everybody, it was really easy. Just needed that nod in the right direction.

Comment: Avoid using relative paths and `CurrentDirectory`; they are often not what you think they are. Instead use a absolute file path every time.

Comment: If those image files are part of your project, make sure they are copied to the output directory (properties of each image should be set to "always", or "newer".

Answer (score 1):

[Environment.CurrentDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

As Steve says in his comment, you must specify the full path otherwise.

You can use [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a path based on the current working directory. Such as:

```
Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Images");
```